# Using ifchanged template tag with timezone aware datetime fields

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following in my template:

```
{% for showtime in showtimes %}
{% ifchanged showtime.start.day %}
<h3>{{ showtime.start|date:"M d" }}</h3>
{% endifchanged %}
```

showtime.start is a timezone aware DateTimeField.  The problem is that *showtime.start.day* returns the day in UTC while *showtime.start|date:"M d"* prints the date in the context timezone.

I've tried the following:

```
{% ifchanged showtime.start|date:"M d" %}
```

which fails since ifchanged can't deal with arguments to filters (even in 1.5).  I've tried playing around with timezone and localtime, eg.

```
{% load tz %}
{% timezone TIME_ZONE %}
{% for showtime in showtimes %}
{% ifchanged showtime.start.day %}
<h3>{{ showtime.start|date:"M d" }}</h3>
{% endifchanged %}
{% endtimezone %}
```

As expected those don't work.  Is there any way to make ifchanged work on the timezoned version of the date time or do I need a custom filter?

Comment: Hey i have exactly the same problem i was wondering what you end up doing?

My question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21199353/ouput-timezone-aware-django-datetime-fields-without-filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the only method I found is with a custom template tag:

```
{% ifchanged showtime.start|localtime|year_month_day %}
```

So I filter the date using localtime and then the custom template tag returns the year, month and day in the proper timezone so ifchanged works.

```
@register.filter()
def year_month_day(value):
    return "%d-%d-%d" % (value.year, value.month, value.day)
```