# Ouput timezone aware django datetime fields without filters

Tags: django, postgresql, templates, timezone

Hi i upgraded to django 1.4 and i want to take advantage of the timezone support, i got a few datetime fields saved in postgres, and they were saved assuming the timezone of my city, once i set

```
USE_TZ = True
```

And set the timezone to my city the date filter tags in my templates output the correct hour(timezoned)

```
{{ concert.datetime|date:'f' }}
```

The problem is: i use the datetime to build my urls, like this:

```
{% url event artist_slug=concert.slug_name hour=concert.datetime.hour %}
```

And those are not correctly timezoned, the hour is still in UTC and that changes my links, something i can't do, it would lose all the page rank and lots of sites link to use, is not feasible, not to mention that it looks weird that the url has a different hour than the one advertised.
I tried this:

```
{% url event artist_slug=concert.slug_name hour=concert.datetime.hour|date:'H' %}
```

Without success, the date filter tag is not applied and an exception is rised. 
I have a fairily large codebase and lots of templates, is there any way to fix this without using an accesor that returns the datetime timezoned?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm going to try to monkey patch the code that builds the datetime objects from the database to timezone the retturned object with the current request tz info.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Django Documentation states:

> Even if your Web site is available in only one time zone, it’s still
>   good practice to store data in UTC in your database. One main reason
>   is Daylight Saving Time (DST). Many countries have a system of DST,
>   where clocks are moved forward in spring and backward in autumn. If
>   you’re working in local time, you’re likely to encounter errors twice
>   a year, when the transitions happen. (The pytz documentation discusses
>   these issues in greater detail.) This probably doesn’t matter for your
>   blog, but it’s a problem if you over-bill or under-bill your customers
>   by one hour, twice a year, every year. The solution to this problem is
>   to use UTC in the code and use local time only when interacting with
>   end users.

Furthermore:

> When time zone support is enabled, Django uses time-zone-aware datetime objects. If your code creates datetime objects, they should be aware too. In this mode, the example above becomes:

```
import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import utc

now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
```

> Time zone aware output in templates When you enable time zone support,
>   Django converts aware datetime objects to the current time zone when
>   they’re rendered in templates. This behaves very much like format
>   localization.

And finally, without monkey patching anything:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/timezones/#template-tags

Comment: Actually i know all these, i have it implemented i got all my internal code using UTC, what i mean is i want all my UTC datetimes automatically localized to the current request tz. It seems such a thing doesnt exists, so i have to change all my code to use an accessor method that does the localization behind the scenes.

Comment: How will you find out the current request TZ (I suppose you are talking about the requesting users TZ)? there is no HTTP method for something like that, additionally why would your project depend on the TZ of the request?
If you are not dealing with the user TZ, then as I mentioned above, there are Django ways to manipulate the TZ without needing to monkey patch anything.

Comment: I get it through various methods from the user yes, and my application is time sensitive, i don't want to manipulate the TZ i want all the datetimes in the context of that request to be localized to it.

Comment: But the current template is in a timezone context,  the timezone of the current user.   However, it is only used when the dates are displayed, not any other purposed (such as ifchanged or the usage described above).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only way I found to work with this is to convert the date to users time zone  and provide a custom template tag to get the piece you want, something like:

```
{% url event artist_slug=concert.slug_name hour=concert.datetime|localtime|hour_of_day %}
```

Where hour_of_day is a custom tag 
returns the current hour in the correct localtime.